# Can someone explain the ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder code

Tags: netty

I am trying to write my own Protobuf frame decoder and I'm basing it off:

https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/master/codec/src/main/java/io/netty/handler/codec/protobuf/ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder.java

I'm just wondering why it creates the `new byte[5];`

Doesn't it just need to read the first byte to get the length. Why does it need the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the length is represented as variable length field as described in [here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints).